# Kotlin multiple setters/getters (generics)

Tags: java, android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

I am using Firestore as my Android app database, and while trying to save data to Firestore, it still saves my 'details' field, even though annotated with `@Exclude`.

Problem occurs because Kotlin generates bridge getters/setters for my generic data class with `Object` instead of only with my provided generic type.

RoomV2.kt

```
data class RoomV2(
    ...
) : DetailableModel<RoomDetails> {

    /** Firestore constructor only */
    constructor() : this(...)
    
    @set:com.google.firebase.firestore.Exclude
    @get:com.google.firebase.firestore.Exclude
    override var details: RoomDetails? = null
    
    ...
}
```

and my DetailableModel with generic parameter:

```
interface DetailableModel<TDetailsModel> {
        var details: TDetailsModel?
}
```

I have decompiled RoomV2 class and it results in:

```
    ...
       @com.google.firebase.firestore.Exclude
       @Nullable
       public RoomDetails getDetails() {
          return this.details;
       }
    
       // $FF: synthetic method
       // $FF: bridge method
       public Object getDetails() {
          return this.getDetails();
       }
    
       @com.google.firebase.firestore.Exclude
       public void setDetails(@Nullable RoomDetails var1) {
          this.details = var1;
       }
    
       // $FF: synthetic method
       // $FF: bridge method
       public void setDetails(Object var1) {
          this.setDetails((RoomDetails)var1);
       }
...
```

There are evidently double getters/setter..

I am relatively new to Kotlin, and I haven't found anything related to the solution on how to prevent Kotlin from generating multiple getters/setters. Is there any way to accomplish this, or to force Firestore to ignore this field on some other way?
Or maybe some way to put annotation on those synthethic bridge methods?

Thank you for your help

Comment: Could you edit the question to be clear which `@Exclude` you are importing? Please show the full path of the import so that we can reproduce exactly what you are observing.

Comment: It is not possible to omit bridge methods, but it is detectable that the methods are synthetic.

Comment: Please edit your question and add the information Doug asked for, and please also respond using @.

Comment: @DougStevenson I have edited question. I am using Exclude from Firestore. As I see it, those methods that are annotated with Exclude are indeed excluded, but I guess that Firestore still finds those synthetic methods and uses those getters to write those fields to Firestore.

Comment: @LouisWasserman so in order for this to work (Firestore not taking bridge methods into account), Firestore SDK should be updated ? Could my classes be rewritten in some way that those bridge methods for generics would not have to be generated?

Comment: @DorianPavetić did you tried to use inline and reified modifiers in the generic class so it might use the class itself instead?

Comment: @YanayHollander I tried, but haven't figured out how to apply it to field or fun in interface. Even if I apply reified to custom fun 'getDetails()' (same erasure) in implementing class (RoomV2), it still generates new fun, not touching those bridge functions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try excluding the backing field itself:

```
...

@field:com.google.firebase.firestore.Exclude
override var details: RoomDetails? = null

...
```

**upd.** The case turned out to be a little trickier.

The reason is that those bridge methods satisfy [these conditions](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-android-sdk/blob/master/firebase-firestore/src/main/java/com/google/firebase/firestore/util/CustomClassMapper.java#L1014-L1036). If `RoomV2` had been in Java, they wouldn't satisfy them, as `@Exclude` on the regular setter would have propagated to the corresponding bridge method, which is how it works in Java.

In Kotlin, it doesn't work the same way. This is also the reason why we don't have a straightforward way to change the 'set-' prefix, which is relevant [here](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-android-sdk/blob/master/firebase-firestore/src/main/java/com/google/firebase/firestore/util/CustomClassMapper.java#L1014). Even with `@set:JvmName(...)` and `@Suppress("INAPPLICABLE_JVM_NAME")`, the original method's name would change at the JVM level, but the name for the bridge method would still start with 'set', as `@JvmName` does not propagate for the same reasons.

It appears that the only relevant approach to effectively exclude those bridge methods is to add an exclusion rule for any bridge method. I've submitted the corresponding [PR](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-android-sdk/pull/5626/files).

Comment: Already tried, does not work, bridge methods do not get annotated with @Exclude

Comment: @DorianPavetić but do they have to? Does it still save 'details' in such configuration?

Comment: Unfortunately, it still saves them. And yes, they do have to, because otherwise Firestore finds them via reflection.

Comment: @DorianPavetić well, I was hoping it only works with fields

Comment: Unfortunately not. But thank you for your help. I have filled an issue to Firestore SDK, so waiting for their response..

Comment: @DorianPavetić do you need `details` as *var*, not *val*?

Comment: Yes, because `details` gets initialized later in the app. For example, RoomV2 is loaded when user loads all rooms, but details loads only when user clicks specific room, and then `details` is set to this model, but that data is kept in separate document

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256482/discussion-between-vlad-guriev-and-dorian-pavetic).

Comment: Seems there isn't a way to prevent bridge methods from being generated, so a fix in Firestore SDK is the least bad solution to given problem. Thank you Vlad for your help, I hope your PR gets approved